# importing of module is creating a problem?

Tags: python

This code is saved as `sunny.py`

```
print("always work")
def raw():
    print("This is original copy guys, Dont need to worry")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    raw()
else:
    print("The function will never run guys")
```

When I import sunny, I can neither see `always work` nor `The function will never run guys` which should have been printed
Also when I use `sunny.raw()`, it says that there is no attribute named raw(). Also, on import of `sunny`, I can't see any error which means that module is properly imported. 
What might be the reason for this ?

Comment: Whatever it is you're importing, it's not this. Maybe you're looking at the wrong file.

Comment: Check `sunny.__file__`.

Comment: means ? I did not get you. I saved this sunny.py and in a new file, I am writing  import sunny. Is there any wrong in this ? Kindly assist

Comment: It works fine for me. Show us how you are importing and running it.

Comment: @Josepharasta: @user2357112supportsMonica is saying that you might have another module called `sunny.py`, maybe as part of your `Lib` folder, which might be being imported instead. Check `sunny.__file__` is the path of your file...

Comment: Show your directory structure (where sunny.py and the file you used to import sunny.py), how you imported sunny, and the command/s you used to run.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code. I have the file main.py aswell as your sunny.py in the same directory. In the main.py file I have:

```
import sunny
```

When importing never include the .py

When the main.py file is run directly the output I get is:

```
always work
The function will never run guys
```

This is correct as the sunny.py script is not being run directly it is an import so __ name __==" __ main __" will be false resulting in "always work
The function will never run guys" being printed.

When sunny.py is run directly and not as an import this is the output:

```
always work
This is original copy guys, Dont need to worry
```

This time name __==" __ main __" will evaluate as true as the script is being directly run and not being imported.

When I run main.py with the following in it:

```
import sunny
sunny.raw()
```

The output is:

```
always work
The function will never run guys
This is original copy guys, Dont need to worry
```

This is correct as the module is first ran as and import to main.py and then the function raw() is called to print out "This is original copy guys, Dont need to worry"

What is your directory structure and what scripts are importing sunny.py? The directory I have setup is:

```
bin/
    main.py
    sunny.py
```